# Is mapping class group topological property?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, examples-counterexamples, mapping-class-group

Is mapping class group topological property ? This means that if $X$ and $Y$ are  homeomorphic topological spaces then $MCG(X) \cong MCG(Y) $.   is this true ? If no what is counterexample? When mapping class group is topological property? (Note that $MCG(X) $ is mapping class group of $X$ )

I use definition of mapping class group in the book " Braids, Links, and Mapping Class Groups.
By Joan S. Birman " page 148:

Let $\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}}$ denote a closed orientable surface of genus g; and let $z_{1}^{0}, \cdots, z_{n}^{0}$ denote $n$ fixed but arbitrarily chosen points on $T_{g} \cdot$ Recall that in Chapter 1 the symbol $\pi_{1} \mathrm{F}_{0, \mathrm{n}} \mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}}$ denoted the pure braid group on $\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}}$ (with base point $\left.\left(z_{1}^{0}, \cdots, z_{n}^{0}\right)\right)$ and $\pi_{1} B_{0, n} \mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}}$ denoted the full braid
group on $\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}}$ (with the same base point). The following similar notation
is meant to suggest relationships to be developed in this chapter:
$F_{\mathrm{n}} \mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}}$ denotes  the group of all orientation preserving homeomorphisms $h: \mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}} \rightarrow \mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}}$ such that, for each i, $h\left(\mathrm{z}_{\mathrm{i}}^{0}\right)=z_{\mathrm{i}}^{0}$
$B_{n} \mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}}$ denotes the group of all orientation preserving homeonorphisms $h: \mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}} \rightarrow \mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}}$ such that $h\left(\left\{z_{1}^{0}, \cdots, z_{n}^{0}\right\}\right)=\left\{z_{1}^{0}, \cdots, z_{n}^{0}\right\}$
These two groups are to be endowed with the compact-open topology.

$\pi_{0}\left(f_{n} T_{g^{\prime}}\right.$
id) denotes the group is called the pure mapping class group of $\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}}$
$\pi_{0}\left(B_{n} T_{g},\right.$ id $)$ denotes the group of path components of $B_{n} T_{g}$ and is called the (full mapping class group of $\mathrm{T}_{\mathrm{g}}$. The notation $M(g, n)$ is also used for this group.

Comment: What definition of mapping class group are you using?  I can't imagine any definition that makes sense for arbitrary topological spaces for which this would not be trivial.

Comment: @EricWofsey . I use definition of mapping class group in the book " Braids, Links, and Mapping Class Groups. By Joan S. Birman " page 148. In above.

Comment: It appears that your definition applies to compact surfaces yet you’re asking a question about general spaces. Is this right?

Comment: @Randall . Yes . But is this true for compact surface ?